# Javascript array element undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am trying out some angularjs stuff. So I have a few arrays. One of them is artists. this is it's basic structure from `console.log(artists);`

[artists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBktq.png)

problem is that I can't access the elements of the array individually. I read up a lot of things regarding associative arrays and may questions on SO but none really helped. So either it is a very silly mistake I am making or it is some thing else.

Here are few results that I got with every array I have.

```
console.log(artists[0]);  //returns undefined
console.log(artists['0']); //returns undefined
console.log(artists.length); // returns 0 in spite of the fact it showed 20 previously
console.log(Array.isArray(artists)); //returns true
```

And yes I created the array like this in a service, ChartService

```
var artists = [];
var artistids = [];
var tracks = [];

$http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search/?q=genre:pop&type=artist').success(function (data) {
        var items = data.artists.items;
        items.forEach(function(item){
            artists.push(item.name);
            artistids.push(item.id);
            var query = trackApi+item.id+'/top-tracks?country=SE'

            $http.get(query).success(function (response) {
                tracks.push({'preview': response.tracks[0].preview_url});

            });
        });


});

return {
  Artists : artists,
  Tracks : tracks
  }
```

And my controller

```
console.log(ChartService.Artists); //runs fine
console.log(ChartService.Tracks); //runs fine

 $scope.tracks = ChartService.Tracks;

 console.log($scope.tracks);  //runs fine
 console.log($scope.tracks[0]);  //returns undefined
console.log($scope.tracks['0']); //returns undefined
console.log($scope.tracks.length); // returns 0 in spite of the fact it showed 20 previously
console.log(Array.isArray($scope.tracks)); //returns true
```

Comment: So, waht confuses you? There is many cases when array can stays empty. Your http request can fail or it can return no items.

Comment: there is an image attached that shows the array from the console. It clearly is not empty.

Comment: I saw the image. But it is not clear have you called the `console.log(artists.length)` immediately after `console.log(artists)`?

Comment: The array is filled asynchronously so make sure you only check the length and content when the callback has been executed. Did you put those `console.log()` calls in the callback or outside, below the code block?

Comment: Yes. Back to back calls in controller. I think I should put the calls in the code. I was just trying not to clutter.

Comment: I edited to make the controller clear.

Comment: Well, you are looking at your `artists` variable to soon, as at that moment the issued `http` requests have not yet received a response.

Comment: I see. @trincot what can be a bypass to this?

Comment: Just put the code, that needs `artists`, inside the `success` callback function, right after `items.forEach(function(item){ .... });` has been done. Just be aware that even there you will not have access to the tracks, which will still be pending for the nested http response.

Comment: Thanks @trincot it worked! On a follow up, if I wanted to use the arrays in controller, when and where can I return those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you check the content of `artists` before the issued http get requests have triggered their responses.

One way to resolve that is to put your code in the `success` callback, like this:

```
$http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search/?q=genre:pop&type=artist').success(function (data) {
    var items = data.artists.items;
    items.forEach(function(item){
        artists.push(item.name);
        artistids.push(item.id);
        var query = trackApi+item.id+'/top-tracks?country=SE'

        $http.get(query).success(function (response) {
            tracks.push({'preview': response.tracks[0].preview_url});
        });
    });
    // here 
    console.log(artists);
});
```

Still, that solves it for `artists`, but then you'd need to do something similar if you need the `tracks`: as you have more then one request providing for that, you'd need to check the length of the `tracks` array and only if it has the complete length, like this:

```
$http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search/?q=genre:pop&type=artist').success(function (data) {
    var items = data.artists.items;
    items.forEach(function(item){
        artists.push(item.name);
        artistids.push(item.id);
        var query = trackApi+item.id+'/top-tracks?country=SE'

        $http.get(query).success(function (response) {
            tracks.push({'preview': response.tracks[0].preview_url});
            if (tracks.length == items.length) { // all done
                console.log(artists, tracks);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In a follow-up question (in comments) you explained you need this in your controller. You might look into [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) or variants of that method. If you need assistance with that, I would suggest to ask a new question.